iCloud option is greyed out and some files in Documents directory missing
I am using MacBook Air M1 running macOS Sonoma 14.5. I have a folder in the Documents directory where I saved my presentations (in different sub-folders each for a different presentation) made in latex beamer.
Surprisingly, I found that in some of these sub-folders, my *.tex* and *.pdf* files are missing, while other files such as *.aux*, *.bib* etc. are present.
A quick Google search suggested to check for the iCloud setting, which I find totally greyed out. Nothing comes on the screen when I click on it.

What could possibly be wrong with iCloud? Is inactivity of iCloud responsible for my lost files? More importantly, how can I get my files back?

Welcome to AskDifferent @phy_std. I think this might be a corrupt user account on your Mac. Do the files show up in your iCloud Drive (accessible from the Files app on iPhones and iPads, or via the icloud.com website)? I'd also recommend running Disk Utility First Aid from the recovery partition (on all volumes of your system drive), and setting up a replacement user account on the same machine if no problems are found, or First Aid fixes them. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/102611 for Disk Utility instructions.

If the files have disappeared completely, I recommend getting in touch with Apple directly to see if there's anything they can do to recover them for you, after first reading any relevant Apple knowledgebase articles.
